# How to select devices in IntelliJ IDEA new UI?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

#### New UI:

[image]

The app is currently running on a connected device, but I don't see any option to connect to another devices (for example, emulator). Here's the previous version of IDE, where I can see multiple devices.

#### Old UI:

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a known problem https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6270 Currently, you can customize the toolbar manually:

- Right-click on main toolbar and select `Customize Toolbar`
  [image]
- Select the needed group and click on `Add Action`
- Dropdown `Plugins | Flutter` and select `Flutter.DevicesSelector`

  [image]

Comment: It was hard to open context menu which is containing **Customize Toolbar** on blank space. It's easier to right-click on right-end buttons('code with me', 'search everywhere' and 'IDE and project settings').

Comment: tl;dr: I was able to select the device with the "Actions" menu (cmd+shift+a on mac), by entering "select device" as action name.

For whatever reason, right-clicking does not work at all for me. I tried on pretty much the entirety of the main toolbar, but nothing happens (no popup to "Customize Toolbar"). I also tried editing it via "Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars" but could not make the DeviceSelector visible in the toolbar. (using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1)